# C++ reading data from txt file and putting it into 2d array

Tags: c++, c++11

I've got a file with numbers separated by a single space and I want to put them into the 2D array. There are 200 rows and 320 numbers each.
This is my code:

```
int data[200][320];
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

file.open("./../../../Data_PR2/data.txt", ios::in);

while (file>> data[i][j])
{
    if (j == 319) {
        j = 0;
        i++;
    } else
        j++;
}
```

And it kinda works, because first rows are correctly inserted but not all rows.

So what's wrong?

Comment: What's wrong with the ones that haven't been inserted correctly?

Comment: have you tried to print the value of  j , reaching to 319 or not

Comment: @Yann, They have different values, like there are different numbers

Comment: @Roushan, I've tried and I saw different numbers, not those that should be there

Comment: Please search the internet for "C++ read file array 2d".  There are already toooo many similar questions on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler method is to use `/` and `%` instead of `if` statement:

```
unsigned int count = 0;
unsigned int row = 0; 
unsigned int column = 0;
while (file >> data[row][column])
{
  ++count;
  column = count % 320;
  row = count / 320;
}
```

Maybe a more efficient method is to treat the array as a single dimension array, since all slots are contiguous:

```
int * p_slot = &data[0][0];
while (file >> *p_slot)
{
  ++p_slot;
}
```

There are other methods, such as *input iterators*.

The above examples do not check for overflow.  Overflow checking is left as an exercise for the reader. :-)

*Note:  This is not an optimization, but a simplification.  Format conversion, out of bounds checking and the process of inputting, make optimizing moot.  The biggest optimization would be reading bigger blocks into memory, then reading from memory; but for this size, it's not worthwhile.*